# Splitting nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary as per below. I am looking to remove the initial `Data` item. To be left with only the inner dictionary `{0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}`.

All the information I have found so far only suggests splitting based on value and as I am after the value of `Data` I am not entirely sure how to specify the split.

**Initial Nested Dictionary**

```
{'Data': {0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}}
```

**Expected Result Dictionary**

```
{0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}
```

Comment: Do you just want to do `varname = data['Data']`?

Comment: By "splitting" do you mean "accessing"? Because that's all you have to do. `mydictionary['Data']` will produce the result you want.

Comment: So how would I access the nested values of 1 for instance ? dictionary['Data'][1]?

Comment: Yes (or `['1']`, can't remember exactly)

Comment: It's `[1]` and not `['1']`, as those keys are integers and therefore should be accessed as such.

Comment: Is there away to actually split them ?

Comment: What do you mean by "split"?

Comment: Surely my question is legitimate, why do people feel the need to down mark for no reason.

Comment: I don't think you have the right idea of what "splitting" is.

Comment: only have `{0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}` as a dictionary

Comment: And you get that by accessing the `'Data'` key's value, just like any dictionary access.

Comment: Well surely splitting is splitting, remove the `Data` and nested values into separate items. Split them?

Comment: So you cant split a nested dictionary into separate dictionaries ?

Comment: That's not splitting.  That's just accessing a dictionary's value which happens to also be a dictionary.

Comment: So what is this `{0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}` if not a dictionary ?

Comment: All i wanted to understand was how to make this its very own dictionary lol `{0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}`

Comment: It is a dictionary.  Splitting has nothing to do with what you want to do.  The answer below is correct.

Comment: but the question im asking is can you split a nested dictionary into separate dictionaries. Im not asking how to access them in their current form.

Comment: It looks like you don't quite understand what a dictionary is. Please check [this documentation about dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not trying to split, but to retrieve one of the values inside the dictionary:

```
d = {'Data': {0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}}
inner = d['Data']
```

`inner` will now contain `{0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}`

A bit more explanation:

Looking at `d`, it contains one key/value pair. The key is `'Data'` and the value is `{0: 'information1', 1: 'information2', 2: 'information3'}`.

Now to get the value from `d` that is associated with the key `'Data'`, we use the syntax with `[]` and use the key:

`inner = d['Data']`

This will return the value and assign that to `inner`. You can then access the values within inner in the same way. So `inner[1]` will be `information2`.

Comment: rje, yes this is great if all i want to do is access the values but i would like to know can you separate nested dictionaries into their own dictionaries.

Comment: sorry @iNoob but what you are asking (separate nested dictionaries into their own dictionaries) does not make sense to me at all. I did show you the way to get at a nested dictionary, what more do you want?

Comment: ok so its safe to assume you cant separate nest dictionaries into their own dictionaries in that case. Thats fine, I will have to access them as you have suggested.

Comment: @iNoob - `inner` _already is_ its own dictionary. Do you want to also remove `d['Data']` from `d`?